# Program not getting displayed on startup

Tags: .net, windows, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have written a C# application for Windows Mobile 6.0 that I would like to be loaded on start up of the device.  I have therefore put as shortcut to the executable in the \Windows\StartUp folder on the device. I have checked the shortcut and it works fine.

My problem is that when I reboot the device the application is loaded but I see the Home screen. If I go to Task Manager I can see it there running. How can I make it so it is visible on start up.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Form.BringToFront](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx)

or

p/invoke [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923858.aspx)

-PaulH

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to the your main Form's Load event to bring it to the fore and make sure it's visible.

Comment: I have tried the .activate event but this just flashes the caption bar. What is the event/command to bring it to the fore?